# Facebook Graph API get private contents

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'd like to know if it's possible to get, with FB Graph Api, my page's private contents, in particular images. Now these contents are public and I can get them without problems, but I wonder if it's possible to let people see them only on my website and no on facebook. I'm using PHP5. Thank you All!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the URL provided by the Facebook API, when ever you send a request to get the photos, you would be provided with the photo id name tags etc, but also you would get an URL pointing to their CDN. When were you place this "[Facebook Graph API for getting photos](http://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/me?fields=photos&access_token=%22PLACE%20YOU%20ACCESS%20TOKEN%20HERE%22)" Link in the URL bar, you would be returned with a JSON object like below.

```
images": [
      {
        "height": 1000, 
        "source": "https://fbcdn-sphotos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xat1/t31.0-8/11312681_1632831730262788_3144782578590532304_o.jpg", 
        "width": 1600
      },
```

The source item, the url of the image you would want from the CDN. You could use this URL in a iFrame or some other technique to display on your page. Hopefully this helps you :)